# Expression<Func<string>> method and unit test which calls it

Tags: c#, lambda

Can someone help break down and explain the following method, and how it relates to the unit test which calls it?

```
static class Class1 
{
  public static Expression<Func<string>> Method1(Interface1 param1, string param2)
  {
    return () => param1.Method2(
      param2
    );
  }
}
```

In unit test. The 'A' class is FakeItEasy:

```
A.CallTo(
  Class1.Method1(
    instanceOfInterface1,
    "someText"
    )
).MustHaveHappened();
```

Comment: Could you provide some more info on Interface1, CallTo and MustHaveHappened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents of the method are actually unrelated to the unit test. The test checks if an object (of a different type) called the `Method1` with these specific parameters `(instanceOfInterface1, "someText")`. The unit test probably executes some code prior to the `MustHaveHappened` check?

The result of this method is an expression which wraps the call to the `Method2` on the `param1` instance, passing the `param2` as the parameter. The `Method2` is not actually invoked. The resulting `Expression<Func<string>>` object contains an expression tree, which can allow you to inspect the method's body programmatically.